# Quarkus - @ConfigMapping: built-in way to show all properties like "toString()", instead of manual building

Tags: quarkus

As `@ConfigMapping` uses interfaces, there are no ways to implement `toString()`; I cannot view all values and nested values without a lot of manual work(reflection and switch case to deal with each type).

Any plan to support easy view of all levels of properties? Like a super class to inherit which handles this manual `toString()` like building?

---

In SmallRye config doc page I read this:

> ToString#
>
> If the config mapping contains a toString method declaration, the config mapping instance will include a proper implementation of the toString method.

But I added `@Override String toString();` method everywhere, Quarkus just complains about cannot find property "to_string".

---

OK I found [this issue](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/20985) which is implemented in [this commit](https://github.com/smallrye/smallrye-config/pull/785/commits/acad6b34103e254a33e04d760873195b67b118af), which exactly adds the sentence I read into the doc; but still not very clear to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding a `String toString()` method in your `@ConfigMapping` will generate the expected `toString()` implementation.

This is only available starting from SmallRye Config `2.11.0` and Quarkus  `2.12.0.Final`, which came out just a few weeks ago. Previous versions will just try to resolve the method as a configuration property. From your description, it seems that is the case, so you may be using an older Quarkus version that does not support this feature yet.

Comment: I guess that's the reason; I have Quarkus 2.7.5. Will try later, thanks.

Comment: is not working for me version 2.13.3.Final. Still have default implementation from Object

Comment: I've tried it with a sample project using 2.13.3.Final, and it worked as expected. Are you able to provide me with a reproducer @DmitriiBorovoi?

Comment: @RobertoCortez my bad, probably cached or some gradle's glitch, now is working perfectly, thanks